# Como converter pixels em RGBA para caracteres?

Tags: c++, imagem, conversão-de-tipo, sfml

Tendo acesso aos pixels de uma imagem qualquer por meio da biblioteca SFML, 
meu objetivo é capturados e convertê-los para caracteres colocando em uma nova matriz (imagem) e depois exibi-la. Para isso eu verifiquei o tamanho da imagem:

```
sf::Vector2u tam = imagem.getSize();
int largura = tam.x;
int altura  = tam.y;
```

Para capturar o formato RGB, uso o seguinte código:

```
// O ponteiro dos pixel originais em RGBA.
const sf::Uint8* pixels = imagem.getPixelsPtr();

Pixel* rgba = (Pixel*) pixels;
// Vetor que armazenará os pixels.
sf::Uint8* saida = new sf::Uint8[4 * largura * altura];

int tamanho = 4 * largura * altura;

for (int i = 0; i < tamanho; i++)
{
saida[i] = pixels[i];
}
```

O que estou fazendo é criar um vetor que esta recebendo o RGBA, mas ainda sem conversão para caracteres, e essa é uma das minha dúvidas como é um vetor como irei controlar quando ele deve quebrar a linha para formar a imagem correta?
Não seria melhor fazer com uma matriz?
Minha outra pergunta é como eu converto esses pixels em caracteres?

Tentei dessa forma, mas sem sucesso:

```
for (int i = 0; i < tamanho; i++)
{
if (atriz[i][j]>=9,4*8)
saida[i] = '@';
}
```

Comment: Oi! Ainda não conseguiu resolver aquela questão? Chegou a consultar os links sobre ASCII art? Foram úteis? [Link 1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/394882/how-do-ascii-art-image-conversion-algorithms-work), [Link 2](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/20435/Using-C-To-Generate-ASCII-Art-From-An-Image) e [Link 3](http://aa-project.sourceforge.net/aalib/)

Comment: Você até pode utilizar uma matriz, mas não é necessário. Pode utilizar a dica dada em uma resposta a sua outra questão: `pixels[4 * (y * largura + x) + 0]` te devolve a componente R do pixel na coordenada `(x, y)`. `+ 1` te devolve a G, `+ 2` a B, e `+ 3` a componente A.

Comment: Existe um erro no seu segundo código. Apesar do código `if (atriz[i][j]>=9,4*8)` compilar corretamente em C/C++, não acredito que esteja produzindo o resultado que você espera. O que você quis dizer com `9,4*8`?

Comment: Olá @carlosrafaelgn tudo bem?! finalmente consegui fazer o que queria hehe :D, eu estava fazendo os cálculos de conversões errados, quando ficar pronto posto o código open source. att

Comment: Legal! Vai ficar interessante! :)

Answer (score 1):

Se você quer uma relação de um caractere por pixel, você deve quebrar a linha a cada `x` caracteres, onde `x` é a largura da imagem. Considere inserir no vetor uma quebra de linha nos índices múltiplos de `x`. Ou, como você mesmo diz, utilize uma matriz.

Já para converter um pixel diretamente em um caractere - nesse caso, você pode terminar por obter imagens bizarras que em nada se parecem com a original, dependendo dos detalhes. Até onde sei, os programas que transformam um vídeo ou GIF animada em uma arte ASCII animada utilizam análise de forma para transformar regiões da imagem em conjuntos específicos de caracteres, i.e.: um pixel preto cercado a esquerda e em cima por três pixels brancos (usando 0 par abranco e 1 para preto porque não consegui desenhar com HTML):

00
01

Pode se transformar em algo parecido com:

|---|
|-||||

Ou

/--|
|-|||

Dependendo do filtro utilizado.